# android framework development

Tags: android, android-source

I am new in android framework development .

I try to add a service in platform/base and then I make the whole platform folder follow a post online.

Now i don't know how this change can be applied to android application.  Do I need to get a new android.jar package for the application?

Thanks

update --------------------------------------------

1. currently  I have the android source code and modified its framework by adding a testservice.java following this :  [Android-Adding SystemService](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService)
2. Then I need to write a test app to use this testservice. But I don't how to add an app to that modified android source code. I try to following this:[set up the Eclipse IDE for Android platform development](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) to add app src path to eclipse build path , I doesn't work.
3. before this i use eclipse and ADT to write android apps, i am wondering is there any way to write an app in the modified android source code ?

Thanks

---

I copied an app under [androidroot]/packages/apps/ folder and rename it and modify some code .  Then it shows in application list. It works!
But the problem is the directory structure is strange , very different from the one I  create from the eclipse + sdk .
So is there anyone know how to develop apps under a modified android framework.

Thanks !!!

Comment: You may want to go into detail about what you are trying to do.  Your question can't be answered without more details.

Answer (score 1):

I see a quick and dirty solution: replace the corresponding android.jar in the install SDK location (for example $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-8/android.jar if you deriver from Android 2.2).

Also you may try to spoof a separate platform revision in $ANDROID_HOME/platforms. Something like android-99 to avoid clashes with the actual future platforms.

Though all of these are dirty tricks this may work for quick testing of your platform code without much pain.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same as the project you create using eclipse. What's more all you need is to write a makefile in the directory. 
Then mmm framework/res   framework    systemserver

bw